# No se puede llamar el objeto "list" al usar Session.add_all

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Tengo inconveniente con este código me genera error:

> id_ccf = input("Digite el nombre de la CCF"))])
>   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

No entiendo el porque, no tengo ningún objeto con nombre 'list'. Este es la parte relevante de mi código:

```
def Agregar():
    Empleados = []
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=eng)
    session = Session()

    session.add_all([
        Empleados(numdocEmp = input("Digite el numero de Documento del Empleado"),
                  tipodocEmp = input("Digite el tipo de Documento del Empleado"),
                  nombre1Emp = input("Digite el primer nombre del empleado"),
                  nombre2Emp = input("Digite el segundo nombre del empleado"),
                  apell1Emp = input("Digite el primer apellido del empleado"),
                  apell2Emp = input("Digite el segundo apellido del empleado"),
                  fechaingEmp = input("Digite la fecha de ingreso del empleado"),
                  cargoEmp = input("Digite el cargo  del empleado"),
                  tipocontEmp = input("Digite el tipo de contrato del empleado"),
                  sbmEmp = input("Digite el salario basico mes del empleado"),
                  fotoEmp = input("foto del empleado"),
                  id_eps = input("Digite el nombre de La EPS"),
                  id_afp = input("Digite el nombre de la AFP"),
                  id_arl = input("Digite el nombre de la ARL"),
                  id_ccf = input("Digite el nombre de la CCF"))])

    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

**Edición:**

De acuerdo a los comentarios he intentado crear mi clase `Empleados` con la siguiente estructura:

```
class Empleados(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'empleados'

    id_Emp = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    numdocEmp = Column(Integer()
    ....


    def __init__(self):
        self.id_Emp = 0
        self.numdocEmp = 0
        self.tipodocEmp = 0
        .....


    def __repr__(self)
        return "<Empleados(numdocEmp = '%s', tipodocEmp = '%s'.............
                      " % (self.numdocEmp, self.tipodocEmp,....
```

Pero ahora obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_arl'

Comment: `Empleados` es una lista, no puedes hacer `Empleados()`, `Empleados` debe ser  una lista de los objetos de la clase `Empleado` (o como la llames) que quieres añadir. Es decir, debe ser algo así: `Empleados  = [Empleado(mundocEmp = ..., tipodocEmp = ...), Empleado(mundocEmp = ..., tipodocEmp = ...), Empleado(mundocEmp = ..., tipodocEmp = ...), ...]` Por supuesto que debes tener definida adecuadamente la clase `Empleado`.

Comment: Entendi, tu comentario pero, al hacer el cambio me surge otro error:

Comment: Aplique:  empleado=Empleados(numdocEmp.......)   > session.add(empleado)   pero surge el error.   >                                    
    id_ccf = input("Digite el nombre de la CCF"))
   >TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_arl'

Comment: Me confunde por que revota el ultimo registro de la lista? (id_ccf)

Comment: Añade la definición de tu clase Empleado o similar a la pregunta para poder evaluar y  reproducir el código.

Comment: Tambien, veo que con esta nueva session cada la ejecuta, type error argumento de clave inesperada con un elemento de la lista diferente.

Comment: class Empleados(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'empleados'

    id_Emp = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    numdocEmp = Column(Integer())
    tipodocEmp = Column(VARCHAR(100)).......

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/124664/edit) la pregunta añadiendo en ella el código mínimo necesario para reproducir el problema, los comentarios son un mal lugar para agregar código (pueden desaparecer, no permiten identado, restricción de longitud, etc). La base de datos que usas y la   estructura de tu tabla también seria interesante que la añadas para saber tipos de datos y nombres de columnas.

Comment: Creo haber encontrado el problema, no era necesario crear el constructor def __init__ 'empleados' generaba confusion al tratar de insertar los registros.  con la creacion de la clase y instancia def __repr__(self): era suficiente. no se tu que opinas

Comment: Jsierra el inicializador actualmente no es necesario de forma explícita pero si que se puede usar, de hecho puede haber casos en los que necesites usarlo. He creado una respuesta explicando lo del error inicial, lo que comentas del `__init__` y dejando un ejemplo totalmente reproducible por si sirve de ayuda a futuros usuarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El error original se debe a que `Empleados` es una lista Python e intentas llamarla al hacer:

```
session.add_all([Empleados(numdocEmp...),...])
```

Debes tener una clase `Empleado` para poder crear objetos que serán apropiadamente mapeados en la tabla correspondiente de tu base de datos.

Creada esta clase podemos instanciar todos los objetos que queramos y crear las filas apropiadas en la tabla usando una sesión mediante `Session.add(<Instancia de Empleado>)` o añadiendo varios objetos a la vez con `Session.add_all([<Instancia de Empleado1>,<Instancia de Empleado2>, ...])`.

Las clases mapeadas usando el Sistema Declarativo se definen dentro de una clase base que mantiene un catálogo de clases y tablas relativas a esa base. Por norma general esta instancia de la clase base será única en la app y se crea instanciando `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base`. En este caso esta clase podría ser algo así:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Empleado(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'empleados'

    id_Emp = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    numdocEmp = Column(Integer)
    tipodocEmp = Column(Integer)
    nombre1Emp = Column(String)
    # Resto de columnas con sus tipos apropiados.
```

En la definición de la tabla (clase `Empleado`) no es necesario en principio usar un inicializador (`__init__`) de forma explícita usando el sistema declarativo actual, si no se proporciona uno explícitamente, la clase aceptará automáticamente argumentos al ser instanciada pero siempre serán de tipo key-word (coincidiendo con los nombres de las columnas definidas como atributos de clase), nunca podrán ser posicionales.

Si queremos o necesitamos incluir nuestro propio inicializador este sobreescribe al anterior. Debe recibir como argumentos aquellos atributos (valor de cada columna) que queramos pasar al inicializar y los atributos inicializados en el tienen que coincidir con el nombre de las columnas declarado como atributos de clase anteriormente.

El error que tienes tras la edición se debe a que en la definición de tu `__init__` no recibe parámetro alguno pero luego intentas pasarle los valores de las columnas al inicializar la clase. Para usar tu propio inicializador debes hacer algo como se muestra en el ejemplo que hay a continuación.

Basado en el ejemplo de la pregunta (la tabla tiene solo 4 columnas para no hacer muy extenso el código) podemos ver un ejemplo totalmente reproducible usando `sqlite`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myexampledb.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Empleado(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'empleados'

    id_Emp = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    numdocEmp = Column(Integer)
    tipodocEmp = Column(Integer)
    nombre1Emp = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, numdocEmp, tipodocEmp,  nombre1Emp): # <<<<<
        self.numdocEmp = numdocEmp
        self.tipodocEmp = tipodocEmp
        self.nombre1Emp = nombre1Emp


    def __repr__(self):
        repr_str = "<Empleado(numdocEmo={}, tipodecEmp={}, nombre1Emp={})>"
        return repr_str.format(self.numdocEmp,
                               self.tipodocEmp,
                               self.nombre1Emp)

# Creamos la tabla
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

#Creamos la sesión
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Añadir un empleado
session.add(Empleado(numdocEmp = 10, tipodocEmp = 1,  nombre1Emp = "Rafael"))

# Añadir varios empleados
empleados = [Empleado(numdocEmp = 14, tipodocEmp = 1,  nombre1Emp = "Luis"), 
             Empleado(numdocEmp = 15, tipodocEmp = 2,  nombre1Emp = "Maria"), 
             Empleado(numdocEmp = 16, tipodocEmp = 3,  nombre1Emp = "Elena")]
session.add_all(empleados)

session.commit()

# Mostramos todos los objetos empleado de la tabla.
res = session.query(Empleado).all()
for empleado in res:
    print(empleado)
```

Comment: Excelente, ilustracion. mas claro no se puede. gracias,